# Node display based on conditional view [NULL] field entry or a Rules expression

Tags: 7, views, rules

I am trying to find a solution to empty user Content Listings shown on a User dashboard (landing page). Ideally I want to show a Mini-panel pane or Custom Content Pane instead of a users listing View which would other wise show an empty table and hence blank space on (in this case a Desktop browser, alternatives to be incorporated via CSS Bootstrap etc).

Should the user not have posted any content then a pane with a (vector.svg) graphic will show in place of the empty view blockspace based on the View being NULL or empty asking them to 'add some content' or maybe a vector graphic to instruct. I have looked at the Conditional View module and Rules, but nothing seems to show such options so I'm not quite sure is this my right approach.

Where and what should be my correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need [flag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) make a global user flag: user_has_content, make a rule: react on event: after saving new content of your special type, add a condition: user author is NOT flagged, inside rules action: flag it, only once your user author will be flagged, then on your view, add relationship to author & one more relationship on the new flag on author, and display content if user is flagged, make another view, display whatever you want if user is NOT flagged, this works also on D8, done.

EDIT: since you are using panels, it's easier, make 2 panes as explained, and in panels add this 2 panes, make your rules inside panels UI, display pane 1 if user is flagged, display pane 2 if user is not flagged.

Comment: pinuueve, Thanks for your prompt attention & reply. I use flags for numerous 'Flags' but never thought of using this for such a purpose. Thanks for the tip, I'll give it a go. I had thought Context or Rules may suffice, but couldn't see anything. Anyhow, cheers and have a happy NY!!

Comment: I've marked this as 'accepted' as is has helped me in finding a solution albeit I have some tweaking to do as my requirements are more ambitious, it has at least given me a direction and something to think about, so I thank you very much. Cheers!!

Comment: The above solution works great! Thank you. It will suffice until I can come back to it in the year.